# Minimum Values from Column based on condition SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get minimum value based on some condition from column in below sample table.

Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  UID VARCHAR(10),
  GID VARCHAR(10),
  OID VARCHAR(10),
  Status VARCHAR(20),
  Delivery_Date DATE,
  BU VARCHAR(10),
  FB VARCHAR(10),
  OC VARCHAR(10),
  Device VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U1', 'PO', '1234', 'free', '2022-12-31', 'EC', 'EC', 'App/Web', 'App');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U1', 'PO', 'PO', 'delivered', '2023-01-01', 'PH', 'E-PH', 'App/Web', 'App');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U1', NULL, '2345', 'paid', '2023-01-05', 'EC', 'EC', 'App/Web', 'Web');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U1', 'P1', '4567', 'delivered', '2023-01-05', 'LB', 'LB', 'B2B', 'Web');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U2', 'P2', 'P2', 'cancelled', '2023-01-05', 'LB', 'CW-LB', 'Offline', 'COT');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U2', 'P3', '9678', 'free', '2023-01-10', 'EC', 'EC', 'App/Web', 'App');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U2', 'P3', 'P3', 'delivered', '2023-01-10', 'PH', 'CW-PH', 'TELE', 'App');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U3', 'P5', '3456', 'Paid', '2023-01-11', 'EC', 'EC', 'App/Web', 'Web');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U3', 'P5', 'P5', 'delivered', '2023-01-12', 'LB', 'PSP-LB', 'Offline', 'Web');

INSERT INTO orders (UID, GID, OID, Status, Delivery_Date, BU, FB, OC, Device)
VALUES ('U4', 'P4', 'P4', 'delivered', '2023-01-12', 'PH', 'PSP-PH', 'B2B', 'App');
```

Tried out query till based on below condition but no luck with exact output

```
SELECT 
    t1.UID AS UID,
    t2.BU AS Acquired_BU,
    t2.Delivery_Date AS Acquired_Delivery_Date,
    t2.FB AS Acquired_FB,
    t2.OC AS Acquired _OC,
    t2.Device as ACquired_Device
FROM
    (SELECT 
        UID, GID, MAX(Delivery_Date) over (partition by UID, GID) AS max_date
    FROM 
        table
    WHERE 
        Status = 'delivered' 
    GROUP BY 
        UID) t1
JOIN
    table t2 ON t1.UID = t2.UID AND t1.GID and t2.GID AND t1.max_date = t2.Delivery_Date
```

Conditions:

Need to find **First Acquired Delivery Date** & **Other similar first attributes** for **each UID** based on conditions (**given status != cancelled**).

1. IF UID has multiple GID records and Delivery Date of BU = EC is minimum for that GID & Status = Free then first acquired date of UID won't be of BU = EC but next minimum delivery date
   **(See U1 & U2 in Expected Output)**
2. If (Status= Paid) for (BU = EC) then we will consider minimum delivery date across all UID records, no condition applied given that there is no Status = Free for same UID.
   **(See U3 in Expected Output)**
3. IF UID has No (BU = EC) record and (Status not in (free, Paid) ) then also consider minimum delivery date across all UID records, no condition applied
   **(See U4 in Expected Output)**

Expected Output from above Sample Table:

| UID | Acquired Delivery Date | Acquired BU | Acquired FB | Acquired OC | Acquired Device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 1 Jan | PH | E-PH | App/Web | App |
| U2 | 10 Jan | LB | CW-LB | TELE | App |
| U3 | 11 Jan | EC | EC | App/Web | Web |
| U4 | 12 Jan | PH | PSP - PH | B2B | App |

Comment: *Sample Table* Provide it as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina Added the table in particular format.

Comment: Your data as a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Pz38PplA

Comment: Your conditions are absolutely unclear. Convert them to linear combination if single steps and conditions. For example.. For each group by UID: 1) If UID has multiple GID records then step 2 else step 10; 2) Get minimal Delivery Date where BU = EC & Status = Free. 3) Return the row with the next Delivery Date where BU <> EC. 10) If exists a row with (Status= Paid) for (BU = EC) then ...